# Is it safe to delete /var/log/memusage?

Tags: linux, logging

I have a 12GB file in /var/log and I'm wondering if it's safe to delete.

```
root@chestnut [/var/log]# ls -alh memusage 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12G May 10 20:23 memusage

root@chestnut [/var/log]# tail memusage 
11450 nobody    15   0 11664 5572 1404 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 httpd              
12824 root      17   0  5984 1528  876 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 crond              
12826 root      18   0  5984 1528  876 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 crond              
12827 root      17   0  2504  900  788 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sh                 
12828 root      23   0  2504  944  824 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 exiwhat            
12831 root      18   0  2508  924  808 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 memusage.sh        
12843 root      16   0  2424  928  692 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top                
12851 root      25   0  1748  380  324 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sleep
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a standard file in anything I've ever seen. It looks like someone has a runaway cron job that spews out the results from `top`.

Check your crontab, and see if another admin on the system has it set up to do this for some reason.

Comment: I don't know where to find memusage.sh, /var/log/memusage seems to be a text file full of lines of output from `top'

Comment: `find / -name memusage.sh` and/or `cat /etc/crontab`. Oh, and you may want to start off with a `killall -9 memusage.sh`

Comment: I don't see anything in `/etc/crontab` and there is no memusage.sh running now. I did find a script at `/opt/scripts/memusage.sh` it `echo`s `top -b -n 1` into `/var/log/memusage`

Comment: I'd `chmod -x /opt/scripts/memusage.sh` at the very least, then start the Spanish Inquisition to find out who put it there and ran it until it spewed out 12GB of crud.

Comment: @Hyppy Thanks for the help, I'm convinced I don't need this.

Comment: Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition.

Comment: You can use lsof to find it also, as in `lsof |grep memusage`, and it will show you all the open files (that contain memusage), so you could probably find where the process was originally started.  Update: looks like you found the file after all, never mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would look and see what that memusage.sh program is, and if it seems to be something you don't quite need at the moment, you could probably kill it, remove (or rename/archive) the file, and start it up again if you want.